# HTML Div element have curved border

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to have the bottom curved in my Header Div. Basically the div should be slanted, i tried the below, and its working in all latest browser's except ie8 & below

```
<div class="HeaderTitle" style="background: #000;">
        <h1 class="header">
            PROMOTIONS</h1>
    </div>


#Container #InnerPages .HeaderTitle 
{
    padding: 115px 0 0 0; background-color: #000; 
    margin-right: -20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); /* Safari and Chrome */ 
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);    /* Firefox */
    -o-transform: rotate(5deg);      /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);     /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
#Container #InnerPages .header
{
    text-align: center; color: #fff; font-size: 30px; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 26px; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* Safari and Chrome */ 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);    /* Firefox */
    -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);      /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);     /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

But this doesnt work in IE & my client is very adamant that it should work in IE 8 :-(

Any help please...

Comment: You can use modernizer.

Comment: This jQuery plugin might help you http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**
Use [IETransformsTranslator](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/)

It's an on-line tool With this tool you can make matrix filter transforms what works on IE6,IE7 & IE8. Just paste you CSS3 transform functions (e.g. rotate(15deg) ) and it will do the rest.

**Solution 2**

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

The rotation property of the BasicImage filter can accept one of four values: 0, 1, 2, or 3 which will rotate the element 0, 90, 180 or 270 degress respectively.

Solution 3

Since this answser is still getting up-votes, I feel I should update it with information about a javacript library called CSS Sandpaper that allows you to use (near) standard CSS code for rotations even in older IE versions.

Once you've added CSS Sandpaper to your site, you should then be able to write the following CSS code for IE6-8:

```
-sand-transform: rotate(25deg);
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want curves for IE8

This will help

```
.div
{
   -webkit-border-radius:4px;        /* older webkit based browsers */
   -khtml-border-radius:4px;         /* older khtml based browsers */
   -moz-border-radius:4px;           /* older firefox */
   border-radius:4px;                /* standard */
   behavior: url(border-radius.htc); /* IE 6-8 */
}
```